# How to use "least" priority in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an attribute directive. I'm not sure what priority it needs to be set to; all I know is it needs to be the last linked directive. What priority should I specify for it?

For example, let's say I have two attribute directives on an element, attributeA and attributeB. I don't know the `priority` of attributeA, but I want attributeB to be linked after attributeA.

Here's the real-world scenario why this "least" (numerically highest) priority is required: `attributeA` and `attributeB` were custom directives created. `attributeB` must run after `attributeA` (or any other custom directives). `attributeA` was initially set with a priority that was numerically lower than `attributeB`. Then someone changed `attributeA`'s priority to a number that was numerically higher than `attributeB`, because this developer didn't know about `attributeB` and that `attributeB` had to be linked last. Consequently, `attributeB` broke because its priority was now numerically lower than `attributeA`.

If there was a way to say "no matter what other directives are on this element, always link `attributeB` last, this wouldn't have happened.

Comment: what do you mean by last priority?

Answer (score 2):

The default priority of directives is 0. `ngRepeat` has 1000 and `ngModel` 500. The lowest prio would be `-1` or any other negative number.